# Convergence of sequence $a_1=a$, $a_2=b$, and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n + a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-\ell -1}}{\ell}$, for some integer $\ell$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As you maybe know, the sequence $a_1=a$, $a_2=b$, and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n + a_{n-1}}{2}$ is convergent to $\frac{a+2b}{3}$, If we change the denominator 2 to arbitrary integer $\ell$, what's the convergent number and prove it.

Comment: The equation in the title does not match the equation in the context when we plug $\ell = 2$. I guess you want to solve $$ a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + \cdots + a_{n-\ell+1}}{\ell}. $$

Comment: Also first $\ell$ member of the sequence should be known, not only the first two.